# How to Automatically convert a String YYYY|MM Column to a Date Column YYYY/MM on Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am pulling data with a Plugin called Supermetrics from Adobe Analytics to Google Sheet.

The Date column is pulled as `String` and I want to create automatically another column that is reading and converting this column to a `Date Format`

```
Input
Year & month    First touch channel Visits
2018|12         Natural Search      12345
2019|01         Natural Search      56789
2019|02         Natural Search      23456
2019|03         Natural Search      78912
2019|04         Natural Search      34567 


Expected Output
Year & month    First touch channel Visits Year & month_dt
2018|12         Natural Search      12345  2018|12
2019|01         Natural Search      56789  2019|01
2019|02         Natural Search      23456  2019|02
2019|03         Natural Search      78912  2019|03
2019|04         Natural Search      34567  2019|04
```

I don't need to do manually by clicking on the menu -> Format->Date

I need a way to do automatically and possibly without conflicts with the plugin, because the data are going to be refreshed daily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this array formula in the table header
`={"Year & month_dt";ArrayFormula(if(A2:A<>"", DATE(LEFT(A2:A,4),RIGHT(A2:A,2),1),))}`

[image]

in order to convert the received dates to your desired format - apply the `YYYY|MM` date format **once** for the whole column

[image]

Comment: It partially works because it reads the column, but the output format is quite weird and is the following:  `43435`
`43466`
`43497`
`43525`  the other question that I have, it is possible to create a dynamic/parametric formula, I mean if I add automatically new data in raw 7,8,9,10 and then with the new update in raw 11,12,13,14,15 it is possible to adapt the script automatically?

Comment: I have updated my answer. This _quite weird format_ (`43435` `43466` `43497` `43525`) shows that the cells contain dates. And how those dates appear on the sheet is already set up **once** for the entire column by you. About your question about the dynamic formula - as I wrote to you in my reply, if you put this formula in the table header (i.e. in one cell), it will work for the whole column